# Implement shortcut keys in a script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a program, and while it is running I'd like to give the user the ability to perform an action e.g. exit the program by pressing ctrl+x .

It would be great if anyone could help, can't seem to find the correct syntax online.

echo "Many thanks"

Comment: `Ctrl-C` will already send `SIGINT` is that what you are talking about?

Comment: You can change key settings with `stty`, but it confuses the heck out of everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can trap the keyboard interrupt `SIGINT` generated by Ctrl+C with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tidy_close() {
    echo "Ending gracefully, stage $1"
    exit 0
}

trap 'tidy_close $stage' INT

while :
do
    (( stage++ ))
    echo "Pondering the answers"
    sleep 2
done
```

The function can have any code you need to shutdown.  The `stage` variable is just to illustrate how to pass a value, if you need it.